# Search by field in a referenced documents

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently struggling with a task, which could be easily solved in a relational DB with a simple JOIN.

I have a collection `user_relations` which stores relations between users in the system and essentially stores referrences to documents from collection `users` as a simple `_id`. Now, we need user to be able to search among users who are related to him/her. How do you accomplish this in mongo (with a performance in mind, considering the fact that user can have a really large number of related users - friends/followers/etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot join collections together in mongodb itself.

Instead you either need to structure your DB design so that say in the example, `user_relations` would be an attribute of `users`.

Or- perform the join effectively in the client app once you have the keys / _ids of the users you want to fetch.

Because you can't perform these joins on the server, it really forces you to consider exactly what information you want to return.

You could easily pass an array of user _ids you want to return and use the `$in` operator to return a set of user documents.

Hope that helps.